# Why is my GO server not displaying my HTML files in the browser?

Tags: go, go-server

I am doing a GO course, and whenever I run my server code, I don't get any errors but when I try to type in "localhost:8080" in the browser, I get a message saying "**localhost** didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONS". I have the same exact code as the course, except I am using HTML and not TMPL. Why isn't my HTML displaying in the browser?

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "html/template"
   "net/http"
)

const portNumber = ":8080"

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   renderTemplate(w, "home.html")
}

func About(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, html string) {
   parsedTemplate, _ := template.ParseFiles("./templates" + html)
   err := parsedTemplate.Execute(w, nil)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("error parsing template:", err)
      return
   }
}

func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", Home)
   http.HandleFunc("/about", About)

   fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Starting App on port %s", portNumber))

   _ = http.ListenAndServe(portNumber, nil)
}
```

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in `func Home`?

Comment: The error returned from template.ParseFiles will probably explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ParseFiles method takes a path. You're missing the `/` after `"./templates"`. So it should be:

```
   parsedTemplate, _ := template.ParseFiles("./templates/" + html)
```